What playback order does VLC use when there is no CTTS box in a MPEG4 file?
I have corrupt mpeg4 files which require frame reshuffling (sample at https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GD7YiVS2z8h0r6UdsPPIXFgnh9RukoeR/view?usp=drive_link )
I had some success using ffmpeg's shuffleframes filter but it requires video reencoding, and I would like to avoid that.
I analyzed those mpeg4 files and observed they have no CTTS box, so I tried adding one with the required offsets, to no avail: VLC 3.0.20 still plays the frames in the wrong order :-(.
To confirm whether CTTS worked as I thought, I crafted the following test video with 100 numbered frames @2fps using ffmpeg: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vp3uKZYgoOFqlMk7GLKOC-_vxzJCMwGQ/view?usp=sharing
I analyzed it and can confirm it includes a CTTS box which defines frame offsets(*), and VLC plays it fine. Good.
Now the weird thing is: if I edit that test MPEG-4 and just remove the CTTS box (resulting in the following file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JMEcyBoz5r0uVDt08ZOumDVngT1PYWm8/view?usp=sharing ), VLC still plays the video in the right order !
So my question is: how does VLC proceed ? I guess it uses some other (redundant) information ?
And, when both that information and CTTS are present and disagree, which ones takes precedence ?
Or, in short, how can I fix frame order in a consistent way ?
Thanks,
Vincent
(*) start of CTTS decoding from test file:
Entry{count=1, offset=16384},   2f => frame encoded at pos.  0 => presented at pos.  0+2=2
Entry{count=1, offset=32768},   4f => frame encoded at pos.  1 => presented at pos.  1+4=5
Entry{count=2, offset=8192},    1f => frame encoded at pos.  2 => presented at pos.  2+1=3
                                1f => frame encoded at pos.  3 => presented at pos.  3+1=4
Entry{count=1, offset=40960},   5f => frame encoded at pos.  4 => presented at pos.  4+5=9
Entry{count=1, offset=16384},   2f => frame encoded at pos.  5 => presented at pos.  5+2=7
Entry{count=1, offset=0},       0f => frame encoded at pos.  6 => presented at pos.  6+0=6
Entry{count=1, offset=8192},    1f => frame encoded at pos.  7 => presented at pos.  7+1=8
Entry{count=1, offset=32768},   4f => frame encoded at pos.  8 => presented at pos.  8+4=12
Entry{count=2, offset=8192},    1f => frame encoded at pos.  9 => presented at pos.  9+1=10
                                1f => frame encoded at pos. 10 => presented at pos. 10+1=11
Entry{count=1, offset=32768},   4f => frame encoded at pos. 11 => presented at pos. 11+4=15
Entry{count=2, offset=8192},    1f => frame encoded at pos. 12 => presented at pos. 12+1=13
                                1f => frame encoded at pos. 13 => presented at pos. 13+1=14
Entry{count=1, offset=32768},   4f => frame encoded at pos. 14 => presented at pos. 14+4=18
Entry{count=2, offset=8192},    1f => frame encoded at pos. 15 => presented at pos. 15+1=16
                                1f => frame encoded at pos. 16 => presented at pos. 16+1=17
Entry{count=1, offset=24576},   3f => frame encoded at pos. 17 => presented at pos. 17+3=20
Entry{count=1, offset=8192},    1f => frame encoded at pos. 18 => presented at pos. 18+1=19


Does the corruption look different if you use a new Chrome tab to play the video file vs using VLC? Drag and drop exact same file into each app's window and see. Try seeking back a few seconds to replay some previous decoded frames eg: do they play more correctly (order-wise) on a second re-watch of same time-point? (2) Is "corruption" actually more like "stuttering and jerky playback"? The picture is fine to me but I understand my laptop hardware struggles to play such high-res smoothly. I suspect it takes longer to decode a single 4K HEVC frame than it's due Presentation time on the clock.

Hi. Chrome doesn't seem to play the video track at all. I just have transport buttons and audio playing...

The display (and decode) orders are stored inside the H.264 and H.265 streams.
Picture Order Count (POC) determines the display (output) order of decoded frames. POC is derived from the slice header. POC becomes the ctts box inside MP4.
I would try to copy the video stream into a H.265 elementary stream - strip the video stream out of the container.
Then secondly re-wrap the video stream into a MPEG-4 container.
ffmpeg -i av.mp4 -codec:v copy -an v.h265

ffmpeg -i v.h265 -codec:v copy -an v.mp4


Just to clarify... the OP's first link (corrupt video) is actually a 4K HEVC video but their other "tests" seems to have made an H264 file. That's why H265 is added to the edit.

Hi. I extracted the video stream and rewrapped it into a new container, to no avail. Video is still jaggy and the new mp4 file has no CTTS box.
You indicate POC detetmines the output order. Is it a field inside the video H264/5 bitstream ?
And when you say POC becomes the CTTS, you mean POC remains inside the bitstream but CTTS is created based on it I guess, right ?
Any advice on how to edit the values in the POC (tool, specification ?)
(oh, and yes, the videos I want to fix are h265 but the "number" test I made used h264 as I focused on the MPEG4 wrapper's CTTS table).
Thanks a lot.

The POC is inside the H.265 stream and remains inside the stream for MP4s. I am guessing the the CTTS table is just ignored by most players. The decoder will do the 'heavy lifting' (re-ordering). Here is a link to the specification: https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-H.265-202407-P/en
I am guessing the POC in the stream is broken.
I think the POC is inside the slice header so you don't have to parser very deep into the stream. But I am pretty sure that the POC is not just a simple counter. So you might be in for a little adventure.

Hi Markus and VC.One. I initially hoped to fix the file at the MPEG4 wrapper level, but I had to learn the basics of H265 decoding to get a grasp of how it works (I'll post a separate question about that as it is off-topic). A search for the term "poc" in the h265 spec returned lots of results but I struggled to find the actual value until I realized the field is called slice_pic_order_cnt_lsb :-) and the decoding process is described in section 8.3.1 "Decoding process for picture order count".
I'm going to dig deeper on that. Thanks again.
